# What velocity must an aircraft achieve for its shock wave to transform to plasma?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, aerodynamics, plasma-physics

A follow-up to [After what speed air friction starts to heat up an object?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/43768/after-what-speed-air-friction-starts-to-heat-up-an-object)

I understand there may be technological limitations at present ... but, is it theoretically possible for a body to travel through the atmosphere so fast that the shock wave transforms to plasma? What velocity would a body need to achieve for this to happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I considered two different approaches to this problem.

An obvious solution method would be to use the same method found in the linked *air friction question* (see "internal references" at the end).  That is, consider the leading edge to cause an adiabatic compression of the air.  The pressure can be found from the velocity, which then implies a temperature since the properties are known.  You know what temperature air will ionize itself, so working backwards you can find a velocity.  Here is what I obtained in miles per hour:

$$ T_2 = \frac{1086.4 kJ/mol}{N_A \frac{3}{2} k} \approx 87,000 K$$

$$\frac{T_2}{T_1} = \left( 1+\frac{1}{2} \rho v^2 / ( 1 atm) \right)^{2/7}$$

$$v = \sqrt{ \left( \left( \frac{87,000}{293} \right)^{7/2} -1 \right) \frac{2 (1 atm)}{1.3 kg/m^3} }$$

$$1.9 \times 10^7 mph$$

(note: this was revised down from 4e7 because I previously neglected the 3/2 factor on k)

FYI, this can also be written as $0.025 c$, which sounds ridiculous.  It seems doubtful that the physical mechanisms would continue to work in the same way as you go so many times faster than the speed of sound, and the velocity of the air molecules themselves.  We continue in search of alternatives...

---

Here is another answer, using the approach suggested in the comments.  That approach is [using this compressible flow equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli%27s_principle#Compressible_flow_equation).  This is an alternative to the above solution.

$$ \frac{v^2}{2}+\frac{\gamma P }{(\gamma-1) \rho} = \text{constant}$$

We have to make a substitution from the ideal gas law, $P/\rho = R_{specific} T$.  The specific gas constant for Air is 287.04 J/(kg*K).  That yields this equation.

$$ \frac{v_1^2}{2}+\frac{\gamma R_{specific} T_1 }{(\gamma-1) } = \frac{v_2^2}{2}+\frac{\gamma R_{specific} T_2 }{(\gamma-1) } $$

Everything above is known except for $T_2$.  Solve for that temperature, which comes from my first equation in this answer, or whatever number you want to use for the onset of ionization of air.  The answer:

$$ 29,354 mph$$

Dare I say, this looks like the *right* way to answer the problem.  I should qualify, I omitted a $\sqrt{-1}$ factor.  As you can see, the $T$ and $v$ in the equation appear to be on the wrong sides.  I haven't figured out a way to argue this away, so I felt I should report it.

---

A problem that struck me as similar was the *relativistic baseball* (see internal references) question.  In this question a baseball magically starts moving at $0.9 c$ and it then follows that the air particles have sufficient energy to cause nuclear fusion on the surface of the baseball.  This can be said without using the air thermodynamic properties of air because for the purposes of the problem, air molecules are basically stationary.  The current problem could basically reduce to the same thing, with the exception that instead of nuclear fusion, we are talking about electron ionization.  This is an interesting dichotomy because one way treats the problem with gas dynamics, and the other treats it as a transport problem.  Qualitatively, it could be difficult to argue for one method over the other.  After all, the high pressure region on the leading edge of the object is basically a cushion to the next row of gas molecules.

The counter-argument to that air is mostly empty space.  It could be that the majority of gas molecules don't even "see" the high pressure region in front, so they can't be affected by it.  The [path length of air molecules](http://www.davidpace.com/physics/graduate-school/mfp-air.htm) is $ \lambda_{mfp} = \frac{kT}{P \sigma} \approx 282 nm$.  Combined with a speed in atmosphere of about $500 m/s$, that means the time between collisions is about $0.5 ns$ ([other sources](http://www.ems.psu.edu/~bannon/moledyn.html) give 0.2).  Let's compare to, say, a space capsule reentry vehicle of $3 m$ diameter, if it travels at $0.05 c$ that means that by the time a Nitrogen molecule collides once, it has traveled about $0.75 cm$.  It seems that even at that speed, we can't credit direct collisions between the air molecules and the craft (unless it's really tiny).  Nonetheless, *some* N2 molecules would probably be hitting the surface, and at this energy they would ionize the living daylights out of the surface.

Let's continue with this calc anyway.  Just take the ionization potential of Carbon, which may be used in the structural materials (the material doesn't matter all that much), and you have $1086.4 kJ/mol$, which translates to an energy of about $11 eV$ per atom.  Use the molecular mass of N2 and you can get a velocity.  Ignore the thermal motion within the gas (the object will be flying much faster), and that's the speed the craft will be traveling at in order for an N2 molecule impinging it directly to ionize some of the surface.  With this method I get:

$$ 16,500 mph$$

Incidentally, this is almost exactly orbital velocity.  However, I should qualify that this has limited convincing power.  The high pressure region on the front of an object moving in atmosphere will only extend outward to a length on the scale of its diameter, and at this speed molecules have plenty of time to collide with each other in that distance.  This is still a better answer than my first number, **so I can say I've narrowed it down to 3 orders of magnitude**.

What does NASA say about this?  Well, [they think](http://www.grc.nasa.gov/WWW/K-12/airplane/sound.html) that ionization happens in reentry.

> The Space Shuttle re-enters the atmosphere at high hypersonic speeds, M ~ 25. Under these conditions, the **heated air becomes an ionized plasma** of gas and the spacecraft must be insulated from the high temperatures.

But now, NASA, is it really a *dense* plasma, or is it [one of those lame sparse plasmas](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/38864/where-on-earth-can-you-find-plasma)?  I would be inclined to think the latter.  Not all molecules have the same speed, and in the chaotic mix near of gas near the thermal shields of a reentry craft I don't doubt that there is some ionization taking place.

Are there some other physics about supersonic flow that could further narrow this down?  There could be, but I don't think it's likely.  Even if you're supersonic, the drag still roughly follows $1/2 \rho v^2$, which dictates the basic energy balance.  Sparse ionization should happen well before the wavefront reaches temperatures that we typically think of as the transition to plasma.  That is more-or-less what I get from the NASA reference.

For the naive calculation to clearly say the air becomes plasma, the craft itself has to travel on the order of the desired plasma temperature, which is around $100,000 K$, which leads to my first number.

---

Internal References:

*Air friction question*: [After what speed air friction starts to heat up an object?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/43768/after-what-speed-air-friction-starts-to-heat-up-an-object)

*Relativistic baseball*: [“Relativistic Baseball”](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/31740/relativistic-baseball)

Comment: Given that the Space Shuttle create a plasma during reentry, I doubt your calculation of 4E7 mph was correct... I'm looking for a chart that shows Cp and $\gamma$ of air vs Mach number and altitude but I can't find it...

Comment: Here it is, sort of. I can't link to the chart I was thinking about from Anderson, High Temperature Gas Dynamics, but [this should do](http://ftp.rta.nato.int/public//PubFullText/RTO/EN/RTO-EN-AVT-116/EN-AVT-116-03.pdf) Check Fig. 1.1, they put the ionization limit at around 10 km/s which seems higher than what the Space Shuttle reaches, and yet I'm pretty sure there is a plasma cloud around the SS. I will research this further...

Comment: I don't understand your first calculation. Ignoring [real gas effects](http://www.grc.nasa.gov/WWW/BGH/stagtmp.html), the stagnation temperature is 10 eV [at a Mach number of](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stagnation_temperature) $\sqrt{(400-1)\frac{2}{1.4-1}}\approx 44$, a speed of about 13 km/s. Though, for communication purposes, ionization starts being significant [at Mach 10](http://www.dtic.mil/cgi-bin/GetTRDoc?AD=ADA496640).

Comment: @mmc What you're referring to is the approach for the 2nd calculation.  The first calculation assumes the gas is compressed until the temperature reaches the ionization temperature.  That's why it's so high, and that's why I didn't just ignore it when I got the other answer.  The difference between the two as I understand it is basically between some ionization versus near 100% ionization.

Comment: @AlanSE I'm also doing a calculation based on adiabatic compression. Can you post your detailed calculation? Your approach in the other post looks right, but you must be making some trivial arithmetical mistake here, because at 0.05 c [even electrons](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=electron+energy+at+0.05c) have energies of almost 1 keV.

Comment: @mmc I added in the specifics for the adiabatic compression calculation, so hopefully that will allow our calculations to converge.  Your statement about electrons is close (enough).  If we consider that all particles directly in the path of the object acquire speeds comparable to the speed of the craft, then we see your conclusion is also correct.  The answer is absurd, and the blame falls on the equation for adiabatic compression.  It must be meaningless in this context.  It doesn't come close to accurately predicting the temperature.

Comment: In other words we need to develop new technologies to be able to move significantly faster than sound (approaching orbital velocity). One more 'what-if' -  What if the surface & nose-cone of the craft were constructed of some kind of tubes larger than 0.75cm extending long enough that this shock wave did not collect?

Comment: @AlanSE You are using the wrong Bernoulli Equation :) The [compressible version](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli's_principle#Compressible_flow_equation) must be used for transonic and supersonic flows but it's easier to get the temperature directly by using [conservation of enthalpy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli's_principle#Compressible_flow_in_thermodynamics): $c_p\,T+\frac{v^2}{2} = c_p\,T_s$.

Comment: @mmc You may be right.  I applied your suggestion and updated the answer with it.  That looks more right than any answer so far.  For the record, that is saying that *the gas compression* leads to nearly full ionization of the gas.  Due to thermal distribution partial ionization may happen much earlier.

Comment: @AlanSE I think that $v_1$ and $T_1$ are in the right place. Using $T_1 = 300K$, $T_2 = 10^5K$ and $v_2 = 0$ I get $v_1^2/2 + (1.4/0.4) \cdot 300 \cdot 300 = (1.4/0.4) 300 \cdot 10^5$. Leaving $v_1$ alone in the LHS: $v_1 = \sqrt{2(1.4/0.4)300(10^5-300)} \approx \sqrt{2.1 \cdot 10^8} \approx 1.4 \cdot 10^4 \frac{m}{s}$, matching your result reasonably well.

Comment: @AlanRominger - Wait, I thought the coefficient of drag was dependent upon speed.  In fact, if memory serves me, it has a local minimum near Mach 3 (still higher than M < 1) and then begins to rise rapidly.  So drag should not be as simple as 1/2$\rho \ v^{2}$, right?  So far as I know, hydrodynamic shocks start to behave "differently" after Mach 5, which is partly why M > 5 is called hypersonic.